# Switch ThumbColor with React-Native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks, switching

I would like to make a switch on my app with react-native. The switch should look like this switch as demonstrated below:
[image]

I've tried with Linear Gradient with unsuccessful

```
<Switch
                    trackColor={{ false: Colors.GrayTransparent, true: Colors.GrayTransparent }}
                    ios_backgroundColor='#3e3e3e'
                    onValueChange={toggleSwitch}
                    value={isEnabled}
                    thumbColor={
                        isEnabled ? (
                            <LinearGradient
                                start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
                                end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
                                colors={['#EED02D', '#9A4A90', '#EB9D27', '#4B77B6', '#C43438', '#C43438']}
                            />
                        ) : (
                            Colors.Blue
                        )
                    }
                />
```

Thank you a lot :)

Comment: [Here's the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch#thumbcolor) for the `<Switch>` component's `thumbColor` prop. Looks like it *has to be* a [`color` value](https://reactnative.dev/docs/colors), so that'd explain why inserting a `<LinearGradient>` component doesn't work outright.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using `Switch` from `react-native` since the `thumbColor` prop does not accept a JSX component, just a color and `LinearGradient` is a component, thus this does not work.

It is not possible to achieve what you want using this component. We either need to create a custom `Switch` component or use a library. I have used [react-native-switch-toggles](https://github.com/nithinpp69/react-native-switch-toggles).

Unfortunately, it does not provide the possibility to use a custom styling for the parent container, which we will need if we want to set a black border and a custom padding.

Thus, I have quickly [forked the repository on GitHub](https://github.com/pgrepds/react-native-switch-toggles-2) and [published a new version on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-switch-toggles-2) which you can install as usual.

```sh
yarn add react-native-switch-toggles-2@2.3.0
yarn install
```

Here is how I have implemented it.

```js
import Switch from "react-native-switch-toggles-2"

const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false)

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ margin: 50 }}>
      <Switch
        containerStyle={{ borderColor: "black", borderWidth: 2 }}
        additionalThumbStyle={{ margin: 2, height: 30, width: 30, borderRadius: 15 }}
        renderActiveThumbIcon={() =>
          selected ? (
            <LinearGradient
              style={{ height: 30, width: 30, borderRadius: 15 }}
              start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
              end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
              colors={["#EED02D", "#9A4A90", "#EB9D27", "#4B77B6", "#C43438", "#C43438"]}>
              <View style={{ height: 30, width: 30, borderRadius: 15 }} />
            </LinearGradient>
          ) : null
        }
        renderInactiveThumbIcon={() =>
          !selected ? <View style={{ height: 30, width: 30, borderRadius: 15, backgroundColor: "#4B77B6" }} /> : null
        }
        activeTrackColor={"#3e3e3e"}
        inactiveThumbColor={"#4B77B6"}
        activeThumbColor={"#4B77B6"}
        size={36}
        value={selected}
        onChange={(value) => setSelected(value)}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
```

The above yields in the following toggle component.

**Disabled**

[image]

**Enabled**

[image]

The white border should be set using a parent container and a padding if necessary.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I really appreciate this, but I have all the time this error, I delete node modules, reset cache but all the time show this

error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-native-reanimated from D:\danks-mobile-app\node_modules\react-native-switch-toggles-2\src\switch\index.tsx: react-native-reanimated could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules\react-native-switch-toggles-2\node_modules
  node_modules

Comment: Yes, this library as a dependency to react-native-reanimated v2. Install it as usual `yarn add react-native-reanimated`.

Comment: No, same error...